# How to make a LevelMenu in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, menu, libgdx

I want make a simple game that the user will can to choose a level from the LevelMenu.
I mean by that like the game "Angry Birds" or "Cut The Rope".
Each ButtonLevel may have: locking, gave three stars.
I can do this by creating for each image a button, but I think it won't be efficient.
So I ask if there is a simple way to do this from libgdx?

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

For the stars, you can create one texture and redraw it multiple times with no significant impact to the speed of your game.

You would only need to load two textures for the stars. One would have three dark stars, second one will have a bright star. Then to show 1/2/3 stars you just draw the bright stars multiple times on top of it.

For locking, you just create one lock texture and overlay it.

Glad to help :)

Comment this post if you want any more information :)

Comment: Yes, but in case that i want to do for example twenty levels with diffrent pictures, what should i do? and thank you very much.

Comment: If it's a colour change then you might be able to tint it when it's being drawn. Otherwise, loads of completely different images would be a bad idea.

Comment: If you're showing a map preview, you could make it so that if you select a level a window will popup with a preview, a play button, back btn ad other stats like records etc